# List of lists problem, URL got repeated the last item from the list

Tags: python

I had problem in solving the below list of lists. Can anyone help? It print out the list correctly but url repeated the last list. Not sure where went wrong?

```
lists = ["FB", "APPL", "MSFT"]
url = f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{list}'
for list in lists:
  print(list)
  print(url)
```

```
FB
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT
APPL
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT
MSFT
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT
```

Answer (score 1):

f-string substitutes the `{list}` just once upon creation, not during subsequent uses. Try `str.format`:

```py
lists = ["FB", "APPL", "MSFT"]
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{l}"
for l in lists:
    print(l)
    print(url.format(l=l))
```

Prints:

```
FB
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB
APPL
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/APPL
MSFT
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT
```

---

NOTE: Don't use variable names such as `list`, `dict` etc. It shadow the built-in Python methods.